# error C2065: 'MIIM_STRING' : undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, windows, shell-extensions, submenu

While Trying to create a Menu to SubMenu using InsertMenuItem:

```
MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) };

mii.fMask = MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM_STRING | MIIM_ID;
mii.wID = uCmdID++;
mii.hSubMenu = hSubmenu;
mii.dwTypeData =  _T("Net&Work Drive Solution");


// InsertMenu ( hmenu, uMenuIndex, MF_BYPOSITION | MF_POPUP, 
            // (UINT_PTR) hSubmenu, _T("NetWork Drive Solution") );

InsertMenuItem ( hmenu, uMenuIndex, TRUE, &mii );
```

> I am getting error C2065: 'MIIM_STRING' : undeclared identifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define `WINVER` to be at least 0x0500.  `MIIM_STRING` is defined like this:

```
#if(WINVER >= 0x0500)
#define MIIM_STRING      0x00000040
...
```